# How to use the input of the PygameMenu add_text_input method

Tags: python, menu, pygame

I'm building a menu for my game with the module PygameMenu (https://github.com/ppizarror/pygame-menu). I want to set an integer in the Menu, which influences my game when I start to play. Setting the integer in the menu is working perfectly, but I have no idea how I can use it.

I'm creating the Menu like this:

```py
new_board_menu = pygameMenu.Menu(surface, back_box=False, bgfun=main_background, ....)
```

then I add the input field like this:

```py
 new_board_menu.add_text_input('x-size: ',
                                 default=Defaults.defaultGridSize,
                                 maxchar=3,
                                 textinput_id='x_size',
                                 input_type=pygameMenu.locals.INPUT_INT,
                                 enable_selection=False)
```

How can I use this input?

Answer (score 0):

i found out, that i can add a onchange function to the add_text_input method:

```
new_board_menu.add_text_input('x-size: ',
                                 default=Defaults.defaultGridSize,
                                 maxchar=3,
                                 textinput_id='x_size',
                                 input_type=pygameMenu.locals.INPUT_INT,
                                 enable_selection=True,
                                 onchange= change_x_size)
```

the function gets the input value as argument.

```
def change_x_size(value):
   print("X size is", value)
```